# Custom taxonomy in short code

Tags: custom-taxonomy, shortcode

I am using short codes in theme for grid display. Code only considers category ids. I also want to add custom taxonomies so it give output as both category posts as well as custom taxonomy posts.

```
    function five_col( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'cats' => '1',
        'num' => '2',
        'offset' => '0',
    ), $atts ) );
    $sq = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => $num, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'order' => 'desc', 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'cat' => $cats, 'offset' => $offset));
    if ($sq->have_posts()) :
    $count = 1;
    $col = 5;
    $out = '<ul class="three_col">';
    while ($sq->have_posts()) : $sq->the_post();
                $thumbClass = ($count == $col) ? 'last' : '';
                    $permalink = get_permalink();
                    $title = get_the_title();
                    $bloginfo = get_template_directory_uri();
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($GLOBALS['post']->ID), '');
                        $thumbnail = $img_src[0];
                    }
                    else $thumbnail = '';
                    $default_thumb = $bloginfo.'/images/post_thumb.jpg';
                    $thumbnail = ( $thumbnail == '' ) ? $default_thumb : $thumbnail;
                        $format = '<li class="'.$thumbClass.'"><a href="%3$s" title="%4$s"><div class="img_thumb"><img src="%1$s/scripts/timthumb.php?src=%2$s&amp;w=70&amp;h=130&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100" alt="%4$s"/></div><h5><a href="%3$s" rel="bookmark" title="' . __( 'Permanent Link to %4$s', 'volt' ) . '">%4$s</a></h5></li></a>';
                        $out .= sprintf ($format, $bloginfo, $thumbnail, $permalink, $title );
            $count++;
            if($count > $col){
            $col = $col + 5;
            $out .= '<li class="clear"></li>';
                }
                endwhile;
                $out .= '</ul>';
                return $out;
        endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is this, but you can add taxonomies in query:

```
new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => $num, 'post_status' => 'publish','taxonomy' => $taxonomy));
```

You can filter by term with `$taxonomy => $term`:

```
$taxonomy = 'seasons';
$term = 'spring'
/* $terms = array('summer','winter')  an array */

new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => $num, 'post_status' => 'publish',$taxonomy => $term));
```

More on [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

**Note:** *taxonomies* and *terms* are not the same thing :)